# log4j.properties value filter

Tags: filter, log4j

Hi:
I am using log4f for the logging in my app,and I want to add a FileAppender to the log,so I have to set the file:

```
log4j.appender.fileout.File=E:\myapp\logs\log.html
```

I wonder if there is any way can replace the absolute file path?

Maybe using something like:

log4j.appender.fileout.File={something}\logs\log.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it's possible:

```
log4j.appender.fileout.File=./logs/log.html
```

Where `E:\myapp` is your application path.